# Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Regions' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a table called `Regions` with an auto increment `ID` column. When adding data to the regions table through my ASP.NET Core application, I get this error:

> Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Regions' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

I know why this is happening, I just don't know how to prevent EF Core from writing a value into this `Id` column. I have tried a few things to try and mitigate this but to no avail.

Here is my model, `dbContext` and the `CreateRegions` method. The primary key on this table is the `RegionId`.

Model class:

```
public partial class RegionsModel
{
    [DisplayName("No :")]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Key]
    public Guid RegionId { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Region Name :")]
    public string RegionName { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

`DbContext`:

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<RegionsModel>(entity =>
    {
        entity.Property(e => e.Id).ValueGeneratedNever();

        entity.Property(e => e.RegionId).HasDefaultValueSql("(newid())");

        entity.Property(e => e.RegionName).HasMaxLength(50);
    });
```

Create region method:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateRegion([Bind("Id,RegionId,RegionName")] RegionsModel regionsModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _context.Add(regionsModel);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(RegionsIndex));
    }
    return View(regionsModel);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change **two things**:

**(1)** The data annotation on your model class needs to be `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` :

```
public partial class RegionsModel
{
    [DisplayName("No :")]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Key]
    public Guid RegionId { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Region Name :")]
    public string RegionName { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

**(2)** Your `OnModelCreating` needs to define the column `Id` as being set on `Add`:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<RegionsModel>(entity =>
{
    // set this to "ValueGeneratedOnAdd" 
    entity.Property(e => e.Id).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

    entity.Property(e => e.RegionId).HasDefaultValueSql("(newid())");
    entity.Property(e => e.RegionName).HasMaxLength(50);
});
```

That defines `Id` to be an `IDENTITY` column in your database table, and sets up EF Core to let SQL Server add a new value "on add" (when inserting a new row into the table) to that column.